# Strategy for solving many-clue detective puzzles

Tags: strategy, mystery

There are some puzzles that require sorting out many possible clues, such as [The SErial Killer's killer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/the-serial-killers-killer-difficult) and [Mysterious Murder Mystery 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4687/mysterious-murder-mystery-3). They are often mysteries. What is a good way to organize and look at the clues in these types of puzzles?

*Disclaimer: I am not using these tips to solve these puzzles and get reputation.*

Comment: The whole purpose of having answers is for it to act as "tips" for future, but if someone is not prepared to do the hard work of understanding each of these, and want shortcuts, I am sorry there arent any other than "use your brain"

Comment: @skv I think OP means to ask "what is a good way to organise and look at the clues to search for the answer?"

Comment: @d'alar'cop I agree, that could be a actually a good question in general and with enough clarifications would probably make a good chat topic, however for a Q&A would'nt the answers still be largely opinion based

Comment: @skv yes it probably would. but most likely so would any "puzzle creation/solving" method that isn't algorithmic and provable.

Comment: @d'alar'cop yes that's exactly my point this is primarily opinion based and hence not acceptable as a question on SE, of course there could be other opinions and I respect them, but still felt it was important to voice mine

Comment: In my puzzle, I recommend that you treat everything as important unless you are 100% sure it's not important.